# Finding a canonical basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $N\colon \mathbb{C}^4 \to \mathbb{C}^4$ be given by

$$N =\begin{bmatrix}1+i&-1-i&i&0\\i&-i&-1+i&0\\-1&1&-1&0\\-1&1&-1&0\end{bmatrix}$$

where $N$ is nilpotent. Find a canonical basis $\alpha.$

My attempt was:

I first tried to find an order of this transformation so I computed $N^2$ and $N^3$:

\begin{equation*}
N^2 = \begin{bmatrix}1&-1&1&0\\1&-1&1&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}\qquad\qquad N^3 = 0_{5\times5}.
\end{equation*}

So the order is $3$.
From here, for convenience I'll write $N$ as $T$.

I found the vector $T^2(x)$ where $T^2(x) \in \ker(T)\cap \operatorname{im}(T^2)$ and found out that 
$$T^2(x) = \begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$$

works.  Then I found the vector $T(x)$ where 
$$T(T(x)) = \begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$$

and $T(x) \in \ker(T^2)\cap \operatorname{im}(T)$ and figured out that $$T(x) = \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\-1\\0\end{bmatrix}$$

works.  Here's where I got stuck. Then I tried to find a vector $x$ such that 
$$T(x) = \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\-1\\0\end{bmatrix}$$

where $x\in \ker(T^3)$ but I couldn't find one.

I'm not sure if I've made a mistake somewhere or it's just impossible to find a canonical basis for this transformation.  Any kind of help would be very appreciated!